# To copy the cell text and the comments to another sheet using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet with comments in each cell. Can i programatically read, copy and the cell text and the comments to another sheet using google apps script? I need this facility with comments and not with notes.

Answer (score 5):

Just discovered, that .moveTo(target) is able to move comments even between sheets.

You can read about it here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#movetotarget

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

This function will move a cell with its comments to a different sheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Original");
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Target");
  sheet.getRange("A1").moveTo(targetSheet.getRange("A1"));
}
```

Comment: how to use the function, can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to interact with commends for Google Apps script.
You can follow [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2566) to see how the implementation of that is coming along (not very fast).